# Xcode 10 - Unable to Localize UINavigation Controller Title

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10, ios12

I have an app that I want to translate to Spanish. The app is very simple and uses a basic UINavigation Controller. The title is set in the main story board:

[image]

To add Spanish I did the followings:

1. Added Spanish in the project Localizations

[image]
My first question to you all is why is showing 4 files in English and 3 Files in Spanish, when I actually have 2 files for English and 2 Files for Spanish

2. I enabled location to the view controller

[image]

[image]

3. I added string file to the project as well. This is for labels and dynamic text within the views, and this is working as expected.

[image]

4. Edited the Main.strings (Spanish)

[image]

When running the app, I edited the scheme, and set the application Language to Spanish.

When the app launched and got to the main screen, I still see Welcome instead of "Bienvenidos" What am I missing?

Other things you should know, when adding localization I enabled and disabled this feature a few times for the storyboard trying different options. Also, when testing the app, I change the settings language to Spanish, I deleted and installed the app multiple times as well.

I'm using Xcode 10.1, Project Format is Xcode 9.3-compatible, iOS deployment target is 12.1

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps someone else. With Xcode 10 the recommended way to do any localization is by selecting your project and perform an export for localization, just go to **Editor > Export For Localization**

Once you exported the project, make any changes to the .xliff files, images, etc. 
In the .xliff file, each translation should have a `<source>, <target> and <note>` tag. In my case, many  tags are missing. I manually added them, did the translation and import the translation into my project.

To import the localization just select your project and go to **Editor > Import Localizations**. Now everything should work as expected.

This video from WWDC helped me resolve my issue
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/404/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you probably have also localized your `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file. So you should have 3 localized files in total, except that for your `Main.storyboard` you have checked all three checkboxes (`Base`, `English` and `Spanish`) and since `English` is your development language, it counts for two.

As for your second question, if you're running in the simulator, just editing the scheme should be fine. Since you told that you enabled and disabled localization for your project something might have broken with Xcode. I've been there as well when I tried to remove a localization. Try to clean you project (`Product` -> `Clean Build Folder`) before running the app or even start the project from the scratch (if possible) without this adding/removing flow. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I did localized LaunchScreen, I didn't see that one file. I did the Clean Build and I still see the same results. I changed the text on ALL string files English and Spanish. English version is working, the Spanish version does not. I still see the "Welcome" as a title and same applies to the other views, none of the titles gets translated.

Comment: something I forgot to mention is that the project is a cocoapod project.